# R: Can you run pairwise dissolves using the arcgisbinding package

Tags: r

I am using the `arcgisbinding` package in R to complement work I am doing in ArcGIS Pro, mainly summary tables on various polygon layers in an ArcGIS project. I will need to run various pairwise dissolves on the various layers as well, and then create further summaries.

See picture below, I am wanting to:

1. dissolve overlapping polygons to create new polygons and
2. calculate the resulting area.

I was wondering if it was possible to actually run the pairwise dissolves in R so I can script the commands in R, and run my summaries then?

That would be easier than using ArcGIS Pro to do all the length pairwise dissolves to create more layers, clicking on the various layers and attributed involved, and then have to read new layers into R to do the final summaries.

Especially as I already have multiple layers and being able to write an R script for one layer would be great because I could then recycle the scripts for the other layers (e.g. just tell R to apply the script to a different layer name).

[image: desired result]

Comment: Add whatever code attempt you have or your question will probably get closed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you explain what a "pairwise dissolve" is? Does it mean to combine all features with a common ID? ie combine all Z=1 features, all Z=2 features etc? And "pairwise" means there's only ever 2 of each? The `sf` package can do all these grouping and merging steps.

Comment: @BERA I don't have code because I'm not aware of there being a function to do what I am asking.

Comment: @Spacedman A pairwise dissolve aggregates features based on whatever attribute(s) you specify. There can be more than 2 but the function within ArcGIS Pro is called a pairwise dissolve so I wanted to refer very specifically to the ArcGIS function so that those familiar with it know exactly what I'm referring to. The graphic I included in my question shows it: 2 discrete polygons but there is some overlap. I want to write code in R to dissolve them together and recalculate the total area of the new polygon (so areas of overlap don't get counted twice).

Comment: Is the documentation online?